# Unable to install OpenShot

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I tried to install OpenShot but unable to install it. It says
[image: screen shot attached]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could be broken dependencies. Can you manually install openshot using a terminal? `sudo apt install openshot`

Answer (score 1):

**Add the PPA to your software sources** you need to open a new Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
```

Next, **refresh your package lists and install the app**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openshot-qt
```